# JBoss Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: jboss7.x, mysql-connector

Good evening all, does any one know anything about this error

```
JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
```

it always appears when i start deploying mysql jar and my application fails to start on the sever `HTTP Status 404` i suffered a lot from that and can't have any solution, please help me.

Note: i used `mysql-connector-java-5.1.24.jar`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That message gets printed because the MySQL driver is not JDBC compliant. That may seem a bit weird, but it's a long-standing known issue:

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62038

The problem is that to be fully JDBC compliant, the driver has to have SQL support conforming to the entry level of the SQL92 standard, but MySQL doesn't support features that are required by that. You read that right: MySQL doesn't support the most basic level of a twenty-year-old standard. Probably the most prominent example of a missing feature is [check constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html). Therefore, the driver is non-compliant, and JBoss logs a message saying so.

However, this does not prevent the driver deploying correctly. As the message says, JBoss deploys it.

If your app is not working, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: Sadly in 2019 this is still true.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these [instructions](https://github.com/akostadinov/edg-examples/blob/master/chunchun/src/main/config/jboss.mysql.txt) to deploy mysql driver to JBoss AS. With connector 5.1.22 as found in fedora18 I've never had a problem. Here is the [module.xml](https://github.com/akostadinov/edg-examples/blob/master/chunchun/src/main/config/jboss/modules/com/mysql/main/module.xml)