# Errors by binding MySQL to JBoss 7.0

Tags: mysql, xml, eclipse, jboss

I'm trying to use MySQL with JBoss 7.0. I've changed the standalone.xml and added the driver and the dataresources inside of it, i've also added the module.xml file in the modules/com/mysql/main folder.

This is a part of standalone.xml:

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="H2DS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>
                        jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
                    </connection-url>
                    <driver>
                        h2
                    </driver>
                    <pool>
                        <prefill>
                            false
                        </prefill>
                        <use-strict-min>
                            false
                        </use-strict-min>
                        <flush-strategy>
                            FailingConnectionOnly
                        </flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>
                            sa
                        </user-name>
                        <password>
                            sa
                        </password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:/mydb" pool-name="my_pool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>
                        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
                    </connection-url>
                    <driver>
                        mysql
                    </driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>
                            root
                        </user-name>
                        <password>

                        </password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>
                            100
                        </prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements/>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>
                            org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
                        </xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <driver-class>
                            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
                        </driver-class>
                        <xa-datasource-class>
                            com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
                        </xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
```

and the module.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

And when i deploy (using eclipse) i get this error:

```
14:36:28,108 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
14:36:28,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
14:36:28,110 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to instantiate driver class "com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.web-adwords-project_war is already registered
14:36:28,132 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
14:36:28,133 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to instantiate driver class "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver": org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.web-adwords-project_war is already registered
```

can anyone help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JBoss Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991364/jboss-deploying-non-jdbc-compliant-driver-class-com-mysql-jdbc-driver)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you think this problem will stay unsolved ?

Comment: Did the linked StackOverflow issue help you?

Comment: No and i saw it actually bevor but i'll let it be with MySQL and work with mongo db but thanks anyway